# How to create an admin panel for Angular Universal project?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I currently have an Angular Universal project which works great, Due to SEO needs iv'e been asked to implement an admin panel to this project where they will be able to update text content on their own.

The reason I'm here is that I need to implement it while saving the SSR functionality, meaning that if I'll send a GET request to one of my pages, I want it to display all the text including the dynamic one which I'll let them edit. 
Because of the reason above I can't have a simple API that I'll trigger from the client part as it won't work without the app actually running.
My idea was to GET all the dynamic data at the server.ts of the app,
and to somehow inject it into the client part, that way I'll keep all the SEO benefits of SSR.

Question is - how would I inject all the data from the server.ts?
Tried to google the solution and the only approach I could find is adding providers to the app.engine
example -

```
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
    { provide: 'dynamicContent1', useFactory: () => "some dynamic data I'll GET from the db prior to this line of code." },
    { provide: 'dynamicContent2', useFactory: () => "some dynamic data I'll GET from the db prior to this line of code2." }    
  ]
}));
```

and then the client part would be -

```
  title = "";
  constructor(private injector: Injector, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      this.title = this.injector.get('dynamicContent1');
    } else {
      console.log('we\'re rendering from the browser, so there is no request object.');
    }
  }
```

Doing the above I thought I'll be able to access `dynamicContent1` from the client using SSR.
The example above doesn't work and throws -

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[{provide:"dynamicContent1", useFactory:useFactory}]: 'deps' required
```

couldn't find an answer to this problem... either way Im not sure if thats even the right approach.

Would love some advice of how should I approach that? how would I get the data before the site loads and how would I inject it into the client to preserve the SSR functionality ?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it's not clear to me. Why can't you have you API retrieve from the DB the data entered from the admin panel?

Comment: I can have an API to retrieve the data from the DB, thats fine. I can't do it from the web as I need this data to be available on the initial GET of the page, without the need of the web to trigger another request to an API. so my question above referrs to how can I inject this data which are being fetched in the server into the browser.
Iv'e solved this problem by changing the use factory from an annonymus arrow function into an actual function that retreives the data. I'll answer my question with code examples in a few. thanks David.